# Не могу программно авторизоваться на сайте, парсинг python

Tags: python, парсер, requests

знатоки. Начал изучать парсинг на пайтоне и столкнулся с проблемой: не могу программно авторизоваться на [сайте](https://kai.ru/;). Сначала думал, проблема в непонятно как рассчитанном параметре, похожем на время UNIX (formDate), но вроде как оно полностью автоматически считается и передаётся.

Код парсера:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import fake_useragent
import time

session = requests.Session()

url = "https://kai.ru/main?p_p_id=58&amp;p_p_lifecycle=1&amp;p_p_state=maximized&amp;p_p_mode=view&amp;_58_struts_action=%2Flogin%2Flogin"
user = fake_useragent.UserAgent().random

headers = {
    'User-Agent': user,
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Host": "kai.ru",
    "Origin": "https://kai.ru",
    "Referer": "https://kai.ru/main",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1"
}

data = {
    "_58_formDate": time.time(),
    "_58_saveLastPath": "false",
    "_58_redirect": None,
    "_58_doActionAfterLogin": "false",
    "_58_login": "login",
    "_58_password": "password"
}

session.headers.update(headers)

response = session.post(url, data=data).text
```

При ручной авторизации вот такие данные форм:

[image: Данные форм, отправляемые при авторизации]

Если выполнить этот кусок кода:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')

inputs = soup.find_all('input')
for input in inputs:
    print(input.get('name'), end=': ')
    print(input.get('value'))
```

Мы получим следующий результат:

```
_58_formDate: 1661931199234
_58_saveLastPath: false
_58_redirect: 
_58_doActionAfterLogin: false
_58_login: login
_58_password:
```

То есть пароль не доходит до сервера.

Подскажите, как можно решить проблему, буду очень благодарен)

UPD: проблема была в куки. Добавил куки, сайт всё принял, но возникла другая проблема. Вместо нужной страницы после авторизации получаю следующее:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta content="1; url=/c" http-equiv="refresh"/>
</head>
<body onload="javascript:location.replace('/c')">
<!--
        The numbers below are used to fill up space so that this works properly in IE.
        See http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q294807 for more
        information on why this is necessary.

        12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
        12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
        12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
        -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Могут без куков не пустить

Comment: @СергейШ разве куки не имеют смысл только тогда, когда я уже авторизовался? Программа в итоге должна будет обеспечить возможность авторизации любому пользователю по логину и паролю, для каждого вручную куки не получить

Comment: @СергейШ вы были правы, не пускал без куки. Но теперь возникла другая проблема, в вопросе дополнил